# delphi reference event object by variable TObject

Tags: delphi

i have component with function getsomedata (key:string;listener:Tlistener)

which listener declared like event as follow :

```
Tlistener = procedure (name,age,sex:string) of object ;
```

but in my component listener manager when i add the new listener takes listener parameter as TObject class like .

```
ListenerManager.addListener(key:string;Listener:TObject);
```

when i complile the code i got error message

> Not enough actual parameters

because Event Object (TListener) and ListenerManager Parameter (TObject).

sample of full function code .

```
procedure getsomedata (key:string;listener:Tlistener) ; 
begin

ListenerManager.addListener(key,listener); //error Here >>> addListener input parameters (key:string;Listener:TObject);

end;
```

how can i resolve it ?

Comment: You meant to have `Listener` parameter of type `TListener`, don't you ?

Comment: i have added procedure code , check it

Comment: try "address-taking" operator - `addListener(key,@listener)`   ///   
Also, when u reply - use @name twiter convention. We are not topic-starters like you and would not be notified of your replies if you wold not address us

Comment: Also, as TLama asked - show the declaration of `TListenerManager.addListener` - the parameter type you quoted is very wrong! Why u made it `TObject` instead of `TListener` ???

Comment: Arioch 'The , i made it TObject beacouse i have multi type of listeners .

Comment: then you should decide how would you tell objects that canbe listeners from those that can not. either by some common ancestor class, or by some common implemented interface, or (most slow and unreliable) using RTTI.
How can your listener tell that which objects can be event sinks and which can not ?  Maybe you'd take some insights from http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2010/08/16/the-visitor-pattern-part-1/3/

Comment: And i repeat - address people with "@name" twitter-like scheme. Look who they do in other questions for example.  I did not got any notifications of this reply of yours and got here by sheer chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
procedure getsomedata (key:string;listener:Tlistener) ; 
begin
  ListenerManager.addListener(key,listener);
end;
```

You are attempting to pass a variable of type `TListener` to the second parameter of `addListener`. That parameter is typed as being `TObject`.

Now, `TListener` is typed as being

```
procedure(name,age,sex:string) of object;
```

A variable of procedural type cannot be passed to a parameter of type `TObject`.

It's rather difficult to know exactly what the correct code would look like because the question doesn't contain enough background information. Perhaps `addListener` should receive a `TListener` rather than a `TObject`. But that's just a guess. If you want more complete advice, then you will need to add sufficient detail to the question.

---

You state in a comment that:

> I can not change the parameter type `TObject` to `TListener`.

In that case you are stuck. It's simply not possible to cast a `TListener` to a `TObject`. Now, you could implement a class that had a single field of type `TListener`, and pass that. But I doubt very much that's really the right solution.

Comment: You understand what I mean.Good.

This is what I want to do ,passing item of Tlistener type to an item of type TObject.

But I can not change the parameter type TObject to TListener in the ListenerManager for many reasons.

Comment: then what should AddListener('abcd', Application) do ? what should AddListener('abcd', Mouse) do ?